# how to add Instagram authentication in ionic 3 and getting an access token for my requests

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, instagram, instagram-api, ionic3

I'm working on sample app for accessing Instagram api .I have created a client app in Instagram and got the client id and client secret.Now how to get the access token and store it for API requests.I'm new to ionic.Thanks in advance.

the url im using using : https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code.

Comment: Can you share the URLs where you used for this integration? So many ways to implement this.But you have to share which way you have done so far.

Comment: this is the URL im using.  https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code.

Comment: Are you using any `plugin` to do this integration or `cloud service` or `Auth0`?

Comment: No ,i want to implement it directly

Comment: You cannot do that with Ionic.You must use one of above method which I have mentioned above.

Comment: i wont be getting a token if i use cloud service

Comment: Yes, you can get the `access token` by using any of the methods which I have mentioned above.